# Error free(): invalid next size (fast) при переопределении размера динамического массива

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Функция получает значения из ввода и помещает в динамический массив, если количество символов превышает размер массива, он расширяется. 
При вводе до 32бит выводится корректно от 32 до 64 выводится некорректно свыше 64 выкидывает ошибку.

```
char* getline()
{
    char c = '\n';
    int p = 8;
    int i = 0;
    char* str = new char [p];

    while (std::cin.get(c) && c != '\n')
    {
        if (i > p)
        {
            p = p * 2;
            std::cout << "i=" << i << "p=" << p << '\n';
            char* strNew = new char [p];

            for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
                strNew[z] = str[z];

            delete [] str;
            char* str = new char [p];

            for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
                str[z] = strNew[z];

            delete [] strNew;
        }

        str[i] = c;
        std::cout << "ix=" << i << "p=" << p << "str = " << str[i] << '\n';
        i++;
    }

    str[i] = '\0';
    std::cout << i;
    return str;
}

main()
{
    std::cout << getline();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, а какое отношение к C++ имеет ваш код, кроме использования new/delete/std::?

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = '\n';
int p = 8;
int i = 0;

char *str = new char [p];

while(std::cin.get(c) && c != '\n') {
    if (i > p) {
        p = p*2;
         std::cout << "i=" << i << "p=" << p << '\n';
        char *strNew = new char [p];
        for(int z=0; z<i;z++)                
            strNew[z] = str[z];           

        // здесь вы удалили память "внешней" str
        delete [] str;

        // здесь вы создали ДРУГУЮ переменную str,
        // под которую выделили память:
        char *str = new char [p];
        for(int z=0; z<i;z++)                
            str[z] = strNew[z];           
        delete [] strNew;           
        // а здесь мы получили:
        // 1) классический memory leak (не освободили память локальной str)
        // 2) запись в освобождённый внешний указатель str в дальнейшем
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте описание решения. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.